# RegEx for matching all non-words except punctuation?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, replace

For sentences like:

```
sent = "This i$s a s[[]ample sentence.\nAnd another <<one>>.
        \nMoreover, it is 'filtered'!"
```

I would like to get:

```
"This is a sample sentence. And another one. Moreover, it is filtered."
```

Thus, I thought using `re.sub` should be the way to go. However, RegEx doesn't work as expected (like it pretty much always does^^).

My idea was to use `\W` to match every non-word and then exclude `[.,;!?]` to keep the punctuation. The last RegEx I've tried was:

```
re.sub(r"(\W[^\.\,\;\?\!])", "", sent)
```

Unfortunately, `[^\.\,\;\?\!]` does match for anything that does not contain an entry of`[.,;!?]`, instead of simply saying 'do *not* match these characters literally'.

How can I exclude these characters from match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\W` needs to be integrated into the negated character class. `\W` is the same as `[^\w]`, so you'll end up with `[^\w.,;!?]`. You should repeat this character class, to match contiguous occurences in a single step - `[^\w.,;!?]+`.

It seems you also want to keep spaces, so you should add them to your character class.

Reeding deeper into your question, you also want to replace newlines with a space and `!` with `.`. This makes it a multiple step solution. First filter out anything unwanted `[^\w.,;!? \n]+`, in a next step replace `\n` with   and `!` with `.`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I negate single spaces? `\s` negates to many characters.